# Why does not work POST routing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the standard authentication mechanism in Laravel.

Route path is:

```
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

HTML form is:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
```

When I submit form I get 404 error.

But path for GET methos works:

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
```

Comment: Test this route with a REST client (Postman, for example) and see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Laravel's helper function `url()` to generate an absolute URL. In your case the code would be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('auth/login') }}">
```

You could also check out the [laravelcollective forms package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html). These classes were removed from the core after L4. This way you could build HTML forms using PHP only:

```
echo Form::open(['url' => 'auth/login', 'method' => 'post'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use {{ URL::route('register') }} function in the action method. In This case the method will be:

`action="{{ URL::route('register') }}"`

and your route file will be:
`

```
Route::get('auth/register',array('as' =>'register' ,'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'));

Route::post('auth/register', array('as' =>'register' ,'uses' =>'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'));
```

`